# mongodb: selecting two values for one field

Tags: mongodb, haskell

**UPDATE** The query below using `$all` works. I've updated the question accordingly.

I have tried this selector:

```
[ pack "tags" =: [ pack "$all" =: [pack "city", pack "urban"]]]
```

I have also been able to use the `"$xxx"`-like operators for other queries, like the following:

```
[pack "dueBy" =: [pack "$gt" =: beginningOfTime, pack "$lte" =: readDate stringDate]]
```

I have a field called `"tags"` that is set to have a value that is a list of tags. For example,

```
["tags" := ["city", "urban", "Rochester"]]
```

When I construct a selector to retrieve a document from the database based on two tags, I use a selector that looks like this:

```
 [ pack "tags" =: [ pack "$all" =: [pack "city", pack "urban"]]]
```

Yet when I try to select based on two tags, I get no results. Selecting based on one tag out of many gives me the correct number of results. Also, selecting on one tag and priority (another field) gives me the correct number of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't know Haskell, but in JavaScript this would be:

```js
db.Note.find({tags: {$all: ['school', '229']} });
```

With `$all` you select documents where the array contains all of the values.

Comment: Thanks, but I still found no results with this `Query` (printed in the haskell GHCI): `{options = [], selection = Select {selector = [ tags: [ $all: ["school","228"]]],`...`

Comment: Could you please try to validate the query with MongoDB CLI? I'd like to know whether the problem is mongo selection logic or haskel driver / syntax.